# Where is the n_periods value in sktime ARIMA coming from?

Tags: python, time-series, arima, sktime

I am trying to use the `sktime` python library for forecasting some time series data.
My `x_train` is of shape (277, 10) with the DateTime as index. My `x_test` is of shape (70, 10)
My code for using ARIMA is:

```
fh = ForecastingHorizon(y_test.index, is_relative=False)
arima = ARIMA()
arima.fit(y=y_train, X=x_train)
y_pred = arima.predict(fh=fh, X=x_test)
```

But the predict step is giving me error:

> X array dims (n_rows) != n_periods. Received n_rows=70 and n_periods=80

I am totally unable to understand where the 80 is coming from. I couldn't find any explanation in the sktime documentation. The index of fh and x_test are matching.

I am also getting similar error in case of `VARMAX`, in case of which it is expecting (89,10) X. where are these numbers coming from? Why can't I predict for any period of time? What am I doing wrong here?